# Dynamically creating a map at compile-time

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, compile-time

I'm implementing Lua in a game engine. All of the functions being exported to Lua have headers that start with `luavoid`, `luaint` or `luabool` just for quick reference of the expected parameters, and so I can see at a glance that this function is being exported.

```
#define luavoid(...) void

luavoid(std::string s) TextMsg()
{
    std::string s;
    ExtractLuaParams(1, s);
    ::TextMsg(s.c_str());
}
```

To actually export a function to Lua, they're added to a dictionary. On startup, the map is used to call `lua_register`.

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, ScriptCall> _callMap = {
    { "TextMsg", TextMsg },
    ...
}
```

There will be a lot of functions exported. Rather than have to maintain this map manually, I'd like to automate its creation.

My first instinct was something with macros at compile-time. I gave up on it initially and started writing a program to parse the code (as a pre-build event), since all the functions can be text-matched with the `luaX` macros. It would create a header file with the map automatically generated.

Then I went back to doing it at compile-time after figuring out a way to do it. I came up with this solution as an example before I finally implement it in the game:

```
using MapType = std::unordered_map<std::string, int>;

template <MapType& m>
struct MapMaker
{
    static int MakePair(std::string s, int n)
    {
        m[s] = n;
        return n;
    }
};

#define StartMap(map) MapType map
#define AddMapItem(map, s, n) int map##s = MapMaker<map>::MakePair(#s, n)

StartMap(myMap);
AddMapItem(myMap, abc, 1);
AddMapItem(myMap, def, 2);
AddMapItem(myMap, ghi, 3);

void main()
{
    for (auto& x : myMap)
    {
        std::cout << x.first.c_str() << "->" << x.second << std::endl;
    }
}
```

It works.

My question is, how horrible is this and can it be improved? All I want in the end is a list mapping a a string to a function. Is there a better way to create a map or should I just go with the text-parsing method?

Be gentle(-ish). This is my first attempt at coding with templates like this. I assume this falls under template metaprogramming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how horrible is this and can it be improved?

Somewhere between hideous and horrendous.  (Some questions better left unasked.)  And yes...

> All I want in the end is a list mapping a a string to a function. Is there a better way to create a map or should I just go with the text-parsing method?

The simplest thing to do is:

```
#define ADDFN(FN) { #FN, FN }

std::unordered_map<std::string, ScriptCall> _callMap = {
    ADDFN(TextMsg),
    ...
};
```

This uses the macros to automate the repetition in the string literal function names and identifiers - there's nothing further substantive added by your implementation.

That said, you *could* experiment with automating things further than your implementation, perhaps something like this:

```
#define LUAVOID(FN, ...) \
    void FN(); \
    static auto addFN ## __LINE__ = myMap.emplace(#FN, FN); \
    void FN()

LUAVOID(TextMsg, string s)
{
    ...
}
```

See it running [here](http://ideone.com/yBT9vU).

The idea here is that the macro generates a function declaration so that it can register the function, then a definition afterwards.  `__LINE__` likely suffices for uniqueness of the identifiers - assuming you have one file doing this, and that your compiler substitutes a numeric literal (which all compilers I've used do, but I can't remember if the Standard mandates that).  The `emplace` function has a non-`void` return type so can be used directly to insert to the `map`.

> Be gentle(-ish). This is my first attempt at coding with templates like this.

Sorry.

> I assume this falls under template metaprogramming.

It's arguable.  Many C++ programmers (myself included) think of "metaprogramming" as involving more advanced template usage - such as variable-length lists of parameters, recursive instantiations, and specialisation - but many others consider all template usage to be "metaprogramming" since the templates provide instructions for how to create instantiations, which is technically sufficient to constitute [*metaprogramming*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaprogramming).

Comment: I was trying to explain how this works to someone not familiar with C++ and was starting to rethink it. It would have failed because there is no function declaration. Then I read your response and I was on the same path. Yay! I should have mentioned that I wanted the function definition to follow adding to the map but you read my mind. Perfect. And for the record, I'm always critiquing my own code so honesty appreciated. I'll mark this as answered when I get around to coding this in a day or so.